# how to get all ListviewItems from a Group in Listview?

Tags: c#

i need get some Items from some Group in Listview Control.

So. how to get all ListviewItems from a Group in Listview ?

please help me. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ListView.Groups[index/key]` collection.

```
foreach (var item in listView1.Groups[1].Items)
{
   //
}
```

Comment: i need get ListviewItems in this Group. Example get item in ListView.Groups[1]. How??

Answer (score 0):

`yourListView.Groups[groupIndex].Items` - Here is list view items collection associated with group