# Get all items of a group in a Windows Runtime ListView

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a `ListView` in a Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime app with the items organized into groups. I want to be able to get a list/collection of all the `ListViewItem`s belonging to a particular group. This is [pretty straightforward in a WPF ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644187/how-to-get-all-listviewitems-from-a-group-in-listview) but I can't find any particular property in the Windows Runtime ListView that'd be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach would be to bind a grouped collection to the ListView so you can access this collection any way you want without relying on the ListView.